# How can I make .py files run using Python Shell by default?

Tags: python, windows-10, python-idle

I made a Python GUI using Tkinter, but when I run it directly (double click the file) it opens the black python window but automatically closes by itself in less than half a second. I found a way to make it open the IDLE editor but it just opens the editor and doesn't run it.

I want it to run the way it runs when you open the IDLE editor and press Run Module. This runs it using Python Shell.

Is there a way I can make it automatically run using Python Shell?

Comment: Name the file with `.pyw` and it won't create a console window.

Comment: Please tag your question with what operating system you're using.

Comment: It is possible that your mygui.py file is missing 'root.mainloop()' or the equivalent to start the GUI.  IDLE lets you omit that during development so that one can interact with tkinter to retrieve values and make changes to widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, one of the comments on the original question is correct.

As Terry Jan Reedy (user:722804) said,

> It is possible that your mygui.py file is missing 'root.mainloop()' or the equivalent to start the GUI. IDLE lets you omit that during development so that one can interact with tkinter to retrieve values and make changes to widgets.

Adding `gui.mainloop()` to the end of my program worked.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **Mark Tolonen**'s comment you should do two things

- rename your file to a `.pyw` from `.py` to prefer console-less runs
- set your system to open `.pyw` files with `pythonw` if that's not configured already

  - Linux: configure xdg-open
  - Windows: right click and choose an application from the context menu (you may need to find where Python is installed to select the `pythonw.exe` executable)

Comment: I've tried this just now, but after doing that, for some reason it doesn't do anything at all anymore. I double click it and nothing happens.

Comment: Re-reading your question, sorry, I believe the comment is inverted and so you may want the opposite of this effect. This will _prevent_ the shell window from appearing, while presumably you want it to stay around.